# phonegap : Sever side link for internal html file...?

Tags: cordova, webview, whitelist

I will develop phonegap app for Android. phonegap version is 3.2

My App's index.html is at web server ( ex:www.mydomain.com/mobileapp/index.html)

That is all right.... Then Im trying to load somepage.html(internal html file) with just an ordinary link.

But load is not. My code in index.html(server side) is below..

<.a href="file:///android_asset/www/somepage.html"> load internal page <./a>

The error is...

D/CordovaLog(18788): null: Line 0 : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/somepage.html

E/Web Console(18788): Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/somepage.html at null:0

I hope I explained this well enough. If anyone has insight that could help with this, it would be greatly appreciated. If anyone has any question, please ask and I'll do my best to answer them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. But you can load external pages (such as index.html from your server) using the `cordova inappbrowser`. In that case, once you are done with index.html, you can return in your app.

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, I will not understand your comment. My coding is possible or not possible?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't call a local resource from a file hosted on a web server. But you can call a file hosted on web server from a local file using a cordova plugin `inappbrowser`. Typically, this will just open a pop up window from your app.

Comment: Thank JunM. Your comment is helpful.  But I am very sad....